# Is there a possibility to change the order of a string with numeric value

Tags: mysql, database, string

I have some strings in my database. Some of them have numeric values (but in string format of course). I am displaying those values ordered ascending.

So we know, for string values, 10 is greater than 2 for example, which is normal. I am asking if there is any solution to display 10 after 2, without changing the code or the database structure, only the data.

If for example I have to display values from 1 to 10, I will have:

- 1
- 10
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9

What I would like to have is

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9
- 10

Is there a possibility to ad an "invisible character or string which will be interpreted as greater than 9". If i put a10 instead of 10, the a10 will be at the end but is there any invisible or less visible character for that.

So, I repeat, I am not looking for a programming or database structure solution, but for a simple workaround.

Comment: quick and dirty: computed column that prefixes with zeros to make length of numeric expected...

Comment: Does this column only contain numbers or is it a mix of numbers and letters?

Comment: @MitchWheat, thank you. Could you give me an example, I am afraid I don't undersand your approach.

Comment: @Ilion, this culumn can containing numbers and letters, but usualy, one row will contain or numbers only, or letters only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try appending the correct number of zeroes to the front of the data:

```
01
02
03
..
10
11
..
99
```

Comment: Great idea Wastie, it seems interesting, but for some reasons, this solution is not suitable for what i want. I think that the php class used to display those data is doing something and still displays those numbers as 1, 2 3 etc. and not as 01, 02, 03 etc.

Comment: But it deservs a +1 from me.

Comment: You could try further concatenation then, but this is a cheap and dirty trick - append another character to the front of the number as well: A01, A02, A03 - thus forcing it to a string as opposed to PHP converting the variant to an integer.

Comment: As an afterthought, this is going to add cycles on to your processing, mind you...

Comment: I know nothing about PHP so with what I've picked up from the web you'd be looking at something like `substr("A0000", -strlen("{$value}")) . $value`.  Could be expensive if you're not paging your data.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to cast the value as an number to then order by it:

```
select col
from yourtable
order by cast(col AS UNSIGNED)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14396/9)

Comment: Thank you bluefeet, but as I sayd, i can only work with data, not with SQL, php or anything else.

Comment: @Milos sorry, I guess my eyes missed that this morning. Too early! :)

Comment: No problem, thank you for the help. :) It steel deservs a +1 from me.

Comment: What do you mean you can't work with SQL? SQL is the language used to send queries to MySQL. You won't be able to do much without it.

Comment: @Ilion, the think is that I have some tools which are developped in PHP. I can't tuch those tools, so no possibility to change the queries etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a mixture of numbers and letters in this column - even if not in a single row - what you're really trying to do is a Natural Sort. This is not something MySQL can do natively. There are some work arounds, however. The best I've come across are:

1. Sort by length then value.

   SELECT 
     mixedColumn
   FROM
     tableName
   ORDER BY
     LENGTH(mixedColumn), mixedColumn;

   For more examples see: http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/natural-sorting-in-mysql/
2. Use a secondary column to use as a sort key that would contain some sort of normalized data (i.e. only numbers or only letters).

   CREATE TABLE tableName (mixedColumn varchar, sortColumn int);
   INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('1',1), ('2',2), ('10',3), 
     ('a',4),('a1',5),('a2',6),('b1',7);

   SELECT 
     mixedColumn
   FROM
     tableName
   ORDER BY
     sortColumn;

   This could get difficult to maintain unless you can figure out a good way to handle the ordering.

Of course if you were able to go outside of the database you'd be able to use natural sort functions from various programming languages.